# Must all CNNs and RNNs not have a fully connected layer in order to be considered as such?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, terminology, dense-layers

In the paper [Wrist-worn blood pressure tracking in healthy free-living individuals using neural networks](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325333417_Wrist-worn_blood_pressure_tracking_in_healthy_free-living_individuals_using_neural_networks), the authors talk about a combination of feed-forward and recurrent layers, as if FC layers cannot be part of the RNN.

So, must all Convolutional Neural Networks and Recurrent Neural Networks **not** have a fully connected layer in order to be considered CNNs and RNNs, respectively? If yes, should we consider CNNs and RNNs with an FC layer "hybrid models"?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure about RNN & LSTM (and it always depends on the task), but for CNN the answer is clearly **no**; CNN routinely include FC layers. Quoting from the highly popular (and recommended) Stanford course [CS231n: Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#architectures):

> ### ConvNet Architectures
>
> We have seen that Convolutional Networks are commonly made up of only
> three layer types: CONV, POOL (we assume Max pool unless stated
> otherwise) and FC (short for fully-connected).

You can easily verify that this is the case for practically all popular CNN models for computer vision in any relevant exposition (e.g. [Illustrated: 10 CNN Architectures](https://towardsdatascience.com/illustrated-10-cnn-architectures-95d78ace614d)).

In fact, the all-convolutional NN (i.e. without FC layers) is considered a special case: see [Striving for Simplicity: The All Convolutional Net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6806).